# Busqueda automatica con ajax + php + jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Paso a comentar primero la idea del proyecto y luego lo poco que logre hasta el momento.
Tengo un excel donde tengo nombres de peliculas, la idea es que automaticamente recorra el archivo y vaya buscando las caratulas de dichas peliculas y almacenar en una tabla el nombre y la direccion de la imagen.
Se como leer el archivo excel y recorrer todas las filas, recuperar en una variable el nombre y almacenar en una tabla, todo atraves de php.
Se como ir recorriendo mi tabla temporal, realizar un insert o un update.
Utilizo la api de "https://api.themoviedb.org" para buscar los datos en este caso solo quiero la caratula, utilizando jquery realizo el pedido por ajax y recupero el dato que yo quiero.
Pero aun teniendo todas estas herramientas no se como hacer para ir recorriendo cada "nombre" realizar la busqueda con ajax, en caso de recuperar la caratula entonces voy a realizar un update de mi tabla donde ahora voy a tener la ubicacion.
Para que no dependa de un click, mi archivo php tiene lo siguiente

```
<?php
    //Voy a recibir el nombre a buscar
    $pelicula = isset( $_POST[ 'pelicula' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'pelicula' ] : "xmen";
    echo "<div id='busco'>$pelicula</div>";
?>
<!-- Aqui muestro la caratula solo para saber que funciona -->
<div id="response-container"></div>
```

y en un principio tengo

```
$( document ).ready( function () {      
    var query= $("#busco").text();  
    $.ajax({
        data: {"api_key" : "miapi", "query" : query},
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?",
        }).done(respuesta);

    function respuesta(data){
        if (data.total_results > 0){
            var output = "<img src=https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+data.results[0]['poster_path']+" width='300' height='300' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-html='true'>"         
            $("#response-container").html(output);              
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Se que es una tontera teniendo todo esto pero no me da la cabeza para encajar las piezas

Comment: En el método respuesta(), después de mostrar la imagen, debes agregar otra llamada AJAX para enviar los datos a PHP y aplicar la actualización.

Comment: Tendría que ser al mismo archivo PHP o género otro que solo realice el update? No generaría conflicto al trabajar de esa manera entonces encolando llamadas Ajax. Ya probaré y veré qué sale gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Desconozco tu proyecto, pero yo lo haría en un mismo script. Respecto al rendimiento, también tengo la impresión de que, al menos la primera vez, será muy lento, pero supongo que omitirás la consulta a themoviedb para registros que ya cuenten con una imagen.